# How to open a Content page after FCM notification click on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I already implement FCM notification on xamarin forms android.so I want,when user click on notification then it will open a Xamarin forms content page.
here is my code for receiving FCM notification:
Inside MyFireMessagingService class-

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
        {
            base.OnMessageReceived(message);
            SendNotificatios(message.GetNotification().Body, message.GetNotification().Title);
        }
        public void SendNotificatios(string body, string Header)
        {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
            builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.AppLauncher);
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
            builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.AppLauncher));
            builder.SetContentTitle(Header);
            builder.SetContentText(body);
            builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound);
            builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
        }
```

so How to open a content page after click on notification?

Comment: Good question, with Xamarin Android you simply have to add an extra to your intent handling it from the Activity you are indicating with Intent.GetStringExtra, but here there is only one activity... I think there is to solve like Montemagno solved the problem of permissions (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin), I'm worried I'm not enough expert.

Comment: PermissionsPlugin is not a solution for solve this topic

Comment: I'm not saying that it solves this problem, only that the approach could be similar. Because also for permissions in theory you have to handle them in each Activity, while in Xamarin Forms there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

As the first thing I have replaced

```
public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        base.OnMessageReceived(message);
        SendNotificatios(message.GetNotification().Body, message.GetNotification().Title);
    }
```

With

```
public override void HandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        CreateNotification(intent);
    }
```

Then created a new method CreateNotification as follows,

```
private void CreateNotification(Object e)
    {
        try
        {
            string title = "";
            string body = "";

            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));

            var i = e as Intent;
            var bundle  = i.Extras;
            title = bundle.GetString("gcm.notification.title");
            body = bundle.GetString("gcm.notification.body");


            intent.PutExtra("title", title);
            intent.PutExtra("body", body);

            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop );
            var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
            builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.AppLauncher);
            builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.AppLauncher));
            builder.SetContentTitle(Header);
            builder.SetContentText(body);
            builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound);
            builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(1, builder.Build());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Now we have to update the MainActivity.cs to handle the push notification click by overriding OnNewIntent method as follows

```
protected async override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);
        var title = intent.GetStringExtra("title");
        //This method will get called while the app is launching from the app icon or from the notification
        if (title != null)
        {
            //Means new Intent from push notification
            //Code to open the page
        }
    }
```

Make sure you have kept LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask in the activity